# Reset scrollbar on ItemsSource change

Tags: wpf, binding, scrollbar, scrollviewer, itemssource

Whenever I change the ItemsSource (or it fires a collection reset), WPF doesn't reset the scrollbar position of ListView/DataGrid to the top. This is no big deal if there is a nice way of doing this manually, but it seems there isn't.

Currently I do:

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop();
ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout();
Grid.ItemsSource = Data;
```

Which is causing some flicker because of UpdateLayout repainting the control first.

The other way is to do:

```
Grid.ItemsSource = Data;
ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop();
```

This doesn't seem to cause any flicker, but because the scroll position is changed AFTER ItemsSource is set, it causes WPF to first iterate over the wrong items in the ItemsSource, before it gets the right items (with offset 0). Because the collection is virtualized this causes needless SQL queries for items that will never be displayed.

Is there another way of doing this which doesn't flicker or retrieves the wrong items first?

Answer (score 2):

Just attached this event on the control that will hold the collection:

Assuming that it is a listbox:

```
lstItems.SourceUpdated += new EventHandler<DataTransferEventArgs>(lstItems_SourceUpdated);
```

Then you will have a event that looks like this.

```
    void lstItems_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewerName.ScrollToTop();
    }
```